# I'm trying to get my data from database in React-Native app

Tags: python, django, react-native, get, fetch

If I put .then(data =>{console.log(data)}), I can see the data but is not displayed in my app. What should I do? Thanks

```
function Home(props) {

const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const loadData = () => {
    fetch(url, {
        method: "GET"
    })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            setData(data)
            setLoading(false) 
        })
        .catch(error => Alert.alert('error', error.message))
};


useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
}, [])
{/* 

            

return (
    <View style={styles.homeText}>
        <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
                return renderData(item)
            }}
            onRefresh={() => loadData()}
            refreshing={loading}
            keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}`}
        />
      )}
```

My model in Django view is:
view.py

```
 class MeasurementsViewSets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Measurements.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MeasurementsSerializer
```

My urls.py is:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('measurements', MeasurementsViewSets)
#router.register(r'measurements', views.MeasurementsViewSets) // this doesn't work either
```

In Django I get: "GET /api/measurements/ HTTP/1.1" 200

Answer (score 0):

You are not fetching the data itself. Only the response.

Change your loadData method to this:

```js
const loadData = () => {
    fetch(url, {
        method: "GET"
    })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(res => { <------------ THIS
            setData(res.data) <----- AND THIS
            setLoading(false) 
        })
        .catch(error => Alert.alert('error', error.message))
};
```